# URLEncoder Cyrillic encode UTF-8 bad result

Tags: java, utf-8, encode, cyrillic

```
String text = URLEncoder.encode("кот", "UTF-8");
System.out.println("\nEncoding result : " + text);
```

**Encoding result :** `%D0%A0%D1%94%D0%A0%D1%95%D0%A1%E2%80%9A`

**But I excpect:** `%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82` (looking here http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

What do I have to do to get `%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82` as the result?

- My file is UTF-8 without BOM.
- If i make it ANSI - all is OK.
- **BUT!** How i can force it to work with UTF-8 without BOM?

Comment: By "your file" you actually mean the Java source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IDE or editor is displaying your source file as UTF-8, but the `javac` compiler is probably using a default encoding according to your OS regional setting. Use the option `javac -encoding utf-8` to override that.